# List of lists in to list of tuples, reordered

Tags: python, list, tuples

How 'pythonic-ly', do I turn this:

```
[[x1,y1], [x2,y2]]
```

Into:

```
[(x1,x2),(y1,y2)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and unpacking operator.

```
>>> l = [['x1','y1'], ['x2','y2']]
>>> zip(*l)
[('x1', 'x2'), ('y1', 'y2')]
```

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: Can u explain how `*` is working or give some links which explain `*`?

Comment: @Vivek You can learn more about the `*` operator here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Aside the fact that this question benefits from `zip` specifically returning a list of tuples, more generally `zip(*X)` can be thought of as the matrix transpose of `X`. Which is useful to people who've done lots of linear algebra and therefore would naturally think of the questioner's required re-ordering as transposition.

Answer (score 2):

Handled more case in give test case.

If there are items in list which have different length.

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

In [20]: import itertools

In [21]: b = itertools.izip_longest(*a)

In [22]: list(b)
Out[22]: [(1, 3, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6, 8), (None, None, None, 9)]
```

Comment: @BhargavRao: Updated answer, and who down voted answer can also check and let me know if it is there is any issue :)